# Good book for studying $S_\infty$.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

I'm looking for any books with some good information involving $S_\infty$ and other Polish groups. Specifically interested in $S_\infty$. This is an extremely amazing topological group, now having witnessed metrizability and admittance of a left invariant metric by Birkhoff-Kakutani. I have recently come across some interesting questions involving how to ascertain a complete metric given a left invariant metric, and whether or not a bi-invariant metric exists. I'm confident, that I have the answer to both, but would prefer a little more "reading material," before I post my answers on here to be destroyed by the math geniuses of the world.

Books and notes I already have or have access to:

Kechris, Descriptive Set Theory; 
Moschavakis, Set Theory; 
Dikran Dikranjan, Intro. to topological groups.; 
Willard, General Topology; 
Munkres, Topology.

Thanks in advance for all input.

Comment: Could you specify what $S_\infty$ is? There are two natural groups to consider: All permutations of integers and the direct limit of finite permutation groups.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear. Yes, $S_\infty$ is meant to be all permutations of, in my book, the naturals. But since the collection of all permutations on a set $X$ with $|X| \leq \aleph_0$ are all equivalent to $S_\infty$, we can say the integers. I have seen other notations, such as Aut($\mathbb{N})$ and $S(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Also, I'm sorry if my English doesn't come across very well, I am still learning.

Answer (score 2):

There are:

- M. Bhattacharjee, D. Macpherson, R. Möller, and P. M. Neumann, *Notes on infinite permutation groups*, 1997.
- P. J. Cameron, *Permutation groups*, Cambridge University Press, 1999.
- J. Dixon, and B. Mortimer, *Permutation groups*, Springer-Verlag, 1996.

The first reference is specifically about infinite permutations groups, the other two have some content about infinite permutation groups.